# Undo all actions performed in last 2 days in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have changed the Android package name to android_pro and thus in all files, the changes are reflected. Every file is showing errors. So is there any way that I can get the code that I had 2 days before on my android studio.

I have the .apk file of my project how can I extract all java and resource files from it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this process which can retrieve the code but i'm not sure if the code after two days can retrieve by android studio.

> Open the project then Right click the file and go to Local History.

Comment: The best way is make a back up next time or use github/gitlab/bitbucket in your future project.